# maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.8.1 is missing

Tags: java, maven

Trying to use 3.8.1 instead of 3.8.0 but get the message:

[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.8.1 is missing, no dependency information available.

My pom.xml works fine with 3.8.0. Except for a specific problem. I am long awaiting 3.8.1. According to Maven Central it seems to be available. But simply changing 3.8.0 to 3.8.1 in my pom.xml led to the warning and the failure message:

Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.8.1 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>11</source>
                <target>11</target>
                <debug>true</debug>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

What do I have misunderstood, seeing 3.8.1 in Maven Central but cannot use it in my pom.xml?

Comment: are you using any ide?

Comment: Just delete the 3.8.1 subdirectory content in your local repository and update.

Comment: Do as @sascha suggested furthermore check your logging output cause I suppose you have transfer issues ...you should activate the checksum policy to prevent issues like this https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2018/10/13/maven-artifact-checksums-what/

Comment: Just deleting the 3.8.1. subdirectory solved the problem

Comment: But the root cause is something different. Usually a transfer issue...

Comment: The path looks like `c:\...\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-compiler-plugin\`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What helped me is surrounding plugins with the following tags:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>    
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Answer (score -1):

I had exactly the same problem. I noticed that in the topicstarter`s code a

```
<groupId>
```

is missing.
That is, there is no "G" in the triple coordinate "G-A-V".

I added a single line from the redCuckoo code:

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
```

And that was the solution in my case.